# Передача данных из родителя в потомка Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Здравствуйте. Начал разбираться недавно с Vue.js. Немного не понял передачу данных между компонентами.
Есть у меня родительский компонент

HTML

```
<template>
<div>
    <table class="costs">
        <tr>
            <th class="costs-title">Дата</th>
            <th class="costs-title">Категория расхода</th>
            <th class="costs-title">Список покупок</th>
            <th class="costs-title">Сумма</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="cost in costs">
            <td class="costs-col"><c-calendar></c-calendar></td>
            <td class="costs-col">{{cost.costCategory}}</td>
            <td class="costs-col">{{cost.costListProduct}}</td>
            <td class="costs-col">{{cost.costPrice}} &#8381;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button v-on:showModal="showModal">Добавить позицию</button>
    <c-modal-cost></c-modal-cost>
</div>
```

JS

```
import Calendar from './Calendar.vue'
import ModalCost from './ModalCost.vue'

export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            costs: [
                {
                    costCategory: 'Автомобиль',
                    costListProduct: 'Бензин, свечи',
                    costPrice: '7 000'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    components: {
        'c-calendar': Calendar,
        'c-modal-cost': ModalCost
    }
}
```

И есть дочерний компонент (модальное окно)

```
<template>
<div class="modal-cost" v-if="modalCostVisible">
    <div class="modal-cost-content">
        <div>

        </div>
        <span @click="modalCostVisible =! modalCostVisible">Закрыть</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
export default {
    props: ['modalCostVisible'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            modalCostVisible: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showModal() {
            this.modalCostVisible = true
        }
    },
}
```

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку "Добавить позицию" отображалось модальное окно. То есть modalCostVisible должен быть true. По разному пытался, не могу понять, как мне передать значение v-on (то что сейчас написано у кнопки - ересь, последнее что увидел на просторах гугла)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button @click="showModal = true">Добавить позицию</button>
<c-modal-cost :modalCostVisible="showModal"></c-modal-cost>
```

Удалить `modalCostVisible` из data модального окна.

Или если хотите использовать метод модального окна, то так:

```
<button @click="$refs.modal.showModal()">Добавить позицию</button>
<c-modal-cost ref="modal"></c-modal-cost>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А не подскажете более подробно, как работает первый вариант? Саму логику?
modalCostVisible - это то что мы указываем в props?
А showModal - это берется с родителя?

Comment: Да, но это просто вариант. В принципе при такой реализации свойство отвечающее за видимость внутри модального окна не нужно, можно  сделать через v-if: <button @click="showModal = true">Добавить позицию</button>
<c-modal-cost v-if="showModal"></c-modal-cost>

Comment: Спасибо большое :)